# The choice of Damping coefficient in thermostat - Classical MD simulation

Tags: computational-physics, molecular-dynamics

It always seems quite tricky to choose the damping coefficient in any thermostat(or barostat). It is also well known that dynamical parameters (like diffusivity, viscosity etc.) of the system is highly dependent on the choice of this damping coefficient (or the friction parameter).

Recently, I have seen a few papers in which they tune the damping coefficients in such a way that they match experimentally observed dynamical parameters (like diffusivity etc.). [For example in this page](https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys466/projects/2007/team_h2o/report/index.html), they use $\gamma=5$ for water which is quite unrealistic, but its observed that in this scenario diffusivity matches with the experimental value. I am not sure to what extent this will replicate my real system. Although it is ideal to carry NVE simulations to obtain the dynamical parameters, I wish to know to which extent can one stretch in tuning the friction parameters, in use of these thermostats and barostats without affecting the system? Is it appropriate to just tune them based on some required dynamical parameter results that I should obtain? By what percentage will they represent the original system?

Comment: IMO for a practical thermostat, you'd need to analyze it numerically. There are just too many variables, like the differing specific heats of the components and medium, medium flow patterns, friction, etc. And its more thn just a damping coefficient. Its a whole impulse response issue (you'd probably have to send the output through a complex kernel)

Comment: @Digiproc : Don't you think its less practical sort of to do a very detailed analysis. I am not exactly concerned about the response of the artificial system, but rather want to look how closely would this represent my real system. I am looking for analytical limits based on the connection to real systems.